# Unique Custom Serial Numbers Generation

Tags: .net, sql-server

I’m developing a new application in which I have to generate a unique custom serial number for each new invoice and I must have a counter for all of the invoices in the system.
The format of the serial number is CCBBBYYYYNNNNNN.

Where:

- C = First two letters of the Company name
- B = First three letters of the branch name
- Y = Year No
- N = Serial number from 000001 to 999999

I need your help to come up with a solution that will avoid any discrepancy in the serial numbers and can support multiple users at the same time. In addition, I need to create and save a counter for each newly-created invoice.
How can I achieve this? What is the best way to do it through the database side or the application side?

I also need to reset the serial number counter to zero at the beginning of every year.

Comment: Invoices get deleted. Happens all the time. Company names change too. Until you think about that, understand the issue, and determine how to handle that there is no point to discussing any implementation. And your description is not clear to me - serial number is "global" or specific to some set of the first three columns?

Comment: Still, I didn’t create any code yet. I’m not asking anyone to do the work for me. I’m looking for guidance and ideas to start implementing the solution and once I have implemented it I will come back and post it for further improvement.
I need some ideas on how to tackle this problem so I can start working on it. There are some ways that I can use to generate serial numbers such as the identity column and sequence in SQL server database for example but they have their limitation and the scope of the solution will be SQL database only.

Comment: So I’m thinking to create a class that will be responsible for generating serial numbers according to the format. But how can I store the last generated number and how can I manage the transactions and locking to satisfy the uniqueness and handle the concurrent users? 
Should I use a text file to store the last generated serial number? Or should I store it in a database?

Comment: What I'm planning to do is:
1. Create a table named (SNGeneration) that contains the flowing filesa. 
• CompanyPrefix 
• BranchPrefix
• YearNo
• LastGeneratedNumber
• RowVersionNo
2. Configure RowVersionNo on the table to be a concurrency token.
3. Create a function in the invoice repository that will retrieve the RowVersionNo, and LastGeneratedNumber from the table.
4. Update invoice and SNGeneration using context transaction.

Answer (score 0):

Let's answer one business question - what if in some case there will no be in the system invoice with the number CCBBB2021000101? Will this have critical influence on the whole business? If yes, this is very strange business.

Let's answer one technology question - what if some data corruption will stuck your system because you'll constantly try to save invoice with the number CCBBB2021000102 but system will reject this because this number already in database? Will this stuck sales department?

My point is that strict invoice numbering is not the purpose of automated system. Look at credit card numbers - they are not serial. More to say they contain control digits which enable check consistensy of it's number and this is real business case. So making much efforts to be consistent in sequential numbering will lead to technical and business problems. Also take in mind that if competitor will see invoice number 000001 in June he will be able to make conclusion on business volume with particular customer.

Better approach is the following:

1. Place date and time (maybe UNIX time?) as a part of invoice number.
2. Register invoice as fast as possible in your database without external dependences which will be a point of failure.
3. Just have sequential incremental database index with each invoice.
4. If really needed!? Replace real invoice number with your beautiful number at the moment when you produce report calculating this number based on real data - sort by CCBBB and append dynamic ROW_NUMBER() within this data and year. (Prediction: This will never be required.)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes, your points are valid but let me explain some points in this regard. These requirements did not exist in the past, but they were imposed by the government (tax authority) on all commercial sectors without exception, and a specific time was given to comply with all new requirements. One of these requirements is the issuance of a serial number for every invoice. The number must be sequential and Unique.

Comment: The serial number can be made up of numbers and letters, but it must be sequenced, so our business team starts suggesting some formats for the serial numbers and this is one of the suggestions.
I’m not saying the suggested format is perfect, but we are trying to come up with a format that can satisfy the requirement.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Sorry, I was wrong discussing suggested format instead of  discussing its implementation. I make another answer which is not obvious but may work in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

Think on using 'cross of the list' approach. First you generate list of sequential numbers for invoices - for a day, week, month or year depending on needed quantity to keep this list short enough. When making invoice you take the next minimal available number from this list and mark it as used. At the next period of time you delete used numbers from list and add new numbers.

This is not ideal solution of course but can be seen as you receive this numbers from regulation authority and just use them instead of producing by yourself.

If having the single sequential list is okay possible format could be YYYYNNNNNN/CCBBB where second part is just reference supplement.